# tkinter add_checkbutton menu not getting a checkmark, though variable is there (MacOS)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a menu:

```
class NodePopup(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master, tearoff=0)
        self.send_disabled = tk.BooleanVar()
        self.add_checkbutton(label="Disable sending", 
            command=self.toggle_send, variable=self.send_disabled)

    def popup(self, node, event):
        self.send_disabled.set(node.some_flag)
        print('send_disabled:', self.send_disabled.get())
        self.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)


class View:
    def __init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.canvas = #...
        # ...
        self.node_popup = NodePopup(self.master)
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-2>", self.popup)

    def popup(self, event):
        node_oval, node = self.find_node(event.x, event.y)
        self.node_popup.popup(node, event)
```

When calling `my_menu.popup(e)`, it always pops up without a checkmark. `print()` prints the right values though.

OS X 10.12, python 3.6.0b4.

What is the problem?

Comment: you run `self.node_popup.popup(event, node)` with two arguments but `def popup(self, event):` expects only one. And what do you do in `self.toggle_send` ?

Comment: The code works for me when I fix all the mistakes, add the missing code, and set `self.send_disabled` to `True` or `False`.

Comment: I test on [this example](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/popup-menu-class/main.py) and it works for me (Linux Mint). Maybe it problem with OSX.

Comment: Thanks @furas! That is one last step I should have make (if I had Linux at hand). I ran the example, and there's no tick on the menu either.
Clearly, the answer is that it's a OS X port bug. I'll go see where to report it.

Answer (score 2):

As this code is reported to work on Linux, I reported a bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue28966, which in turn was closed.

Due to a [known problem](http://bugs.python.org/issue18458), Python for OS X comes without a built-in Tk, and uses outdated Tk distribution from Apple. One needs to [install an ActiveTcl](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/).

As a workaround, I changed the text the way it's clear that the meaning of menu item changed:

```
self.entryconfig(
    0, label='Enable sending' if node.m_bSendOff else 'Disable sending')
```

Comment: you can remove `def change()` in reported code - it was used only by `Button()` to change checkbutton.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at any working example of Menu.add_checkbutton, you'll see that it is using an IntVar, not a BooleanVar.  The state of a Tk checkbutton is, in fact, not a boolean: it takes on the values specified by the `offvalue` and `onvalue`options, which are 0 and 1 by default but could be set to any value.

Comment: `offvalue/onvalue` can be `True/False` or any strings too. Try `offvalue="Hello", onvalue="World"` and `StringVar()`.

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work either. Maybe it's a bug in particular tkinter version.